# Alternative to using mpfr arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, bignum

I am trying to write a function in C++ using MPFR to calculate multiple values. I am currently using an mpfr array to store those values. It is unknown how many values need to be calculated and stored each time. Here is the function:

```
void Calculator(mpfr_t x, int v, mpfr_t *Values, int numOfTerms, int mpfr_bits) {
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfTerms; i++) {
        mpfr_init2(Values[i], mpfr_bits);
        mpfr_set(Values[i], x, GMP_RNDN);
        mpfr_div_si(Values[i], Values[i], pow(-1,i+1)*(i+1)*pow(v,i+1), GMP_RNDN);
    }
}
```

The program itself has a while loop that has a nested for loop that takes these values and does calculations with them. In this way, I don't have to recalculate these values each time within the for loop. When the for loop is finished, I clear the memory with

```
delete[] Values;
```

before the the while loops starts again in which case, it redeclares the array with

```
mpfr_t *Values;
Values = new mpfr_t[numOfTerms];
```

The number of values that need to be stored are calculated by a different function and is told to the function through the variable numOfTerms. The problem is that for some reason, the array slows down the program tremendously. I am working with very large numbers so the thought is that if I recalculate those values each time, it gets extremely expensive but this method is significantly slower than just recalculating the values in each iteration of the for loop. Is there an alternative method to this?

EDIT** Instead of redeclaring the array over each time, I moved the declaration and the delete[] Values outside of the while loop. Now I am just clearing each element of the array with

```
for (int i = 0; i < numOfTerms; i++) {
            mpfr_clear(Values[i]);
}
```

inside of the while loop before the while loop starts over. The program has gotten noticeably faster but is still much slower than just calculating each value over.

Comment: pow(-1,i+1) looks like an expensive way to change the sign.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you are doing inside a `while` loop: `mpfr_init2` (at the beginning of the iteration) and `mpfr_clear` (at the end of the iteration) on `numOfTerms` MPFR numbers, and the value of `numOfTerms` depends on the iteration. And this is what takes most of the time.

To avoid these many memory allocations by `mpfr_init2` and deallocations by `mpfr_clear`, I suggest that you declare the array outside the `while` loop and initially call the `mpfr_init2` outside the `while` loop. The length of the array (i.e. the number of terms) should be what you think is the maximum number of terms. What can happen is that for some iterations, the chosen number of terms was too small. In such a case, you need to increase the length of the array (this will need a reallocation) and call `mpfr_init2` on the new elements. This will be the new length of the array for the remaining iterations, until the array needs to be enlarged again. After the `while` loop, do the `mpfr_clear`'s.

When you need to enlarge the array, have a good strategy to choose the new number of elements. Just taking the needed value of `numOfTerms` for the current iteration may not be a good one, since it may yield many reallocations. For instance, make sure that you have at least a N% increase. Do some tests to choose the best value for N... See [Dynamic array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array) for instance. In particular, you may want to use the C++ implementation of dynamic arrays, as mentioned on this Wikipedia article.

Comment: I once asked here about something similar to vectors in C++ to use with mpfr but I don't think one exists.

Comment: @A.Wong C++ vectors is a C++ notion that doesn't exist in C (where dynamic arrays have to be implemented by the end user). So, it is not possible to have them in the MPFR library, which just provides a C interface.

Comment: Hmm. I guess I should teach myself how to implement dynamic arrays. Thanks!